# Equivalence class of cobordant manifolds is a set

Tags: category-theory, cobordism

How can it be seen that if we take the category of (oriented) $n$-dimensional compact smooth manifolds with boundary and identify them up to co-bordism that this is in fact a set? I am reading that one can define a group structure on these equivalence classes, by using disjoint union (and picking suitable orientations/embeddings for the cobordism in the oriented case), but I'm still unsure how to see this is a set.

It is mentioned [here](http://people.math.umass.edu/~weston/oldpapers/cobord.pdf) by Tom Weston, and also in Stong's "Notes on Cobordism theory" that it follows from the [Whitney Embedding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem), (possibly also using the idea of [doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(manifold))) that since one can embed an $n-$dimensional manifold with boundary into $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$, you can consider in that case representatives of the category of smooth manifolds of all dimension as sub manifolds of $\Bbb{R}^\infty$.  Then they say that this is a small category and that should mean that the representatives form a set.

I don't quite see how you can tell it's a small category, and actually I'm not sure what they mean by sub-manifold in that case either. I know there are ways to put topologies on $\Bbb{R}^\infty$, but I'm not sure in what way this is a manifold or in what sense the word sub-manifold is meant.

Comment: Even just giving a representative of each smooth manifold as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ suffices.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Is there a kind of counting argument to see that? And you're saying manifolds up to diffeomorphism already form a set, so the cobordism is just an equivalence relation on the set of classes there? Cheers for the comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It gives an upper bound of the power set of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ for diffeomorphism classes, which is certainly a set.

Comment: @KevinCarlson That's pretty handy thanks! I think that pretty much answers my question, if you 'd like to make it answer? I suppose I don't really need to think about defining submanfolds, since there's very clearly distinct copies of $\Bbb{R}^{2n}\subset \Bbb{R}^\infty$ where the diffeomorphism classes lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every manifold is diffeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, of which there are only a set. In fact there are only continuum many diffeomorphism classes of manifolds, though this is a bit more trouble to show. As for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, the idea is what you suggest: they're submanifolds of any of the canonical finite dimensional subspaces.